# Register broadcast receivers for SCREEN_ON / SCREEN_OFF in a service

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

Can someone confirm whether I'm following proper design of desired functionality?

I need to listen two types of intents by broadcast receivers when my app is at least once ran on a device, which cannot be registered in AndroidManifest:

- android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON
- android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF

For this reason I've created a service, which is started when my MainActivity is launched. 
Withing the service's method `onStartCommand` I register these broadcast receivers...

Next within these broadcast receivers there is done some stuff based on a flag taken from SharedPreferences either 0 (don't do anything) or 1 (do proper logic)

Do I undestand the lifecycle of service correctly, that it will not be stopped / killed (assiming that it doesn't cause any device disturbences and overloading) by Android even the MainActivity will be removed from the memory / stack and intents will be listening ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

- register the Receivers in the Service's `onCreate()` instead since this method is only called once in the creation of the service. If you call `startService()` multiple times, that results in more calls to `onStartCommand()`, which means you're constantly remaking the receivers.

> Note that multiple calls to Context.startService() do not nest (though
>   they do result in multiple corresponding calls to onStartCommand()),
>   so no matter how many times it is started a service will be stopped
>   once Context.stopService() or stopSelf() is called;

- Make sure to unregister your Receivers. I usually do this in `onDestroy()`

Also, about your lifecyle question - a normal service should not be killed without reason and should run independently from the Activity that launched it (bound Services are a bit different from what I remember) but it still runs in the UI Thread and the same process (unless you specify otherwise). However, if a long time passes and your Service isn't in the foreground. It has the potential to be killed. This is why you should make `onStartCommand()` return `START_STICKY`. If the system does kill the Service, when it can, it will restart it. Your Service may also be killed if it is in the foreground, but it is as a last resort kill. `START_STICKY` can be bad if your Service is error prone though. For example, my Service kept crashing. `START_STICKY` made it restart some time later, and then it crashed again, the cycle repeated.

The only times your service is safe from being killed under normal circumstances are these:

> If the service is currently executing code in its onCreate(),
>   onStartCommand(), or onDestroy() methods, then the hosting process
>   will be a foreground process to ensure this code can execute without
>   being killed.